# UML composition 1.* and 0.*

Tags: uml

I have a question in UML. I'm a beginner in UML and I do not know if I can do this :

[image: UML]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. A composition means a whole/part relationship and it can only be 0*-1, 1*-1 or 0*-0..1 at most.

For more information on the subject I'd read this:
https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html

EDIT: Think about what a whole/part relationship is. A bedroom is part of a house, but the same bedroom cannot belong to multiple houses. However, a house can have multiple bedrooms. This is the same kind of relationship as in the house/bedroom case.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. But if I create a new class between fiche_artiste and musique how can I do that musique can be destroy when fiche_artist is detroyed too ?

Comment: I don't know French but I guess that musique is a song or whatever from the artist... The only thing you have to do is remove the * part in the "Fiche_Artiste" class, because a song can only belong to an artist. If you want to allow multiple artists to participate in the same song, you'll have to create an intermediate class for that.

Comment: @Pierre Colart propose your new schema and we will see.

Comment: @CarlosManuelHernández thanks, but I want that this song will destroy if all artists are detroyed ?? how i can i do ?

Comment: I think you'll have better luck opening a new question, since this was already answered. @PierreColart I guess someone with better understanding of UML than me will help you better.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Carlos Manuel Hernadez's answer, the multiplicity in a composition relationship is restricted in the end that touches the whole so that in the upper limit it is at the most 1 for which only the following are allowed: 0..1, 1 and 0 in cases of redefinition. The UML standard 2.5.1 on the page 122 says:

> Composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part object be included in at most one composite object at a time. If a composite object is deleted, all of its part instances that are objects are deleted with it.
>
> NOTE. A part object may (where otherwise allowed) be removed from a composite object before the composite object is deleted, and thus not be deleted as part of the composite object.

And on the page 207 there is an example:
[image]

The other end, as far as I know, has no restrictions so that any multiplicity is allowed (0, 1, 0..1, n, n..m, *, etc.)

With respect to the cascade elimination, this is not limited only to the composition ralationship. You can model an association without any kind of aggregation and put a constrain or an annotation on it to indicate that the existence of an object is conditioned to the existence of the other

Sorry for the bad English, my native language is Spanish